# With apollo client how do you set loading status on mutation refetchQueries?

Tags: react-apollo, apollo-client

So I'm adding to an object's list with a mutation using the apollo client.  Say I have an event and I'm adding participants and i'm using refetchQueries to get the refreshed event with participants on the details screen.  Unfortunately I'm not getting a `data.loading == true` status during this refetch, making it likely that the user will keep hitting that join participant button repeatedly.

```
<Button styleName="dark full-width" onPress={()=> {
            this.props.joinEvent({
                variables: { eventId: Event.id, userId: user.id },
                refetchQueries: ['getEvent'],
              });
              // how do I trigger the data.loading = true like it does during the initial fetch?
          }
        }>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Apollo React documentation isn't great on this, but there is an [open issue](https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/issues/321) to improve it.

Instead of looking at the `data.loading` property, you'll want to use `data.networkStatus`. It will change to `4` during a refetch ([networkStatus values](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/blob/master/src/queries/networkStatus.ts#L4)).

However, in order to get this value to update, you'll also need to set the `notifyOnNetworkStatusChange` option to `true` in your query options.

Using the React `graphql` higher-order component, this looks like:

```
var myQuery = gql`
    query MyQuery {
        ...
    }
`;

var myComponentWithData = graphql(myQuery, {
        options: {
            notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true
        }
    }
)(MyComponent);
```

Comment: Also, I just noticed that when you add the option for `notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true` the `data.loading` property does update on refetch as well.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that, when we call refetchqueries with variables something like 
{
query: query_name,
variables: your_variables
} 

the network status will not changed 

passing the name only not like an object will work

Answer (score 7):

use awaitRefetchQueries:true, it will wait until refetch query resolves
[awaitRefetchQuery](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/)